# How to change the project owner in GitLab

Tags: gitlab

How can I change the project owner in GitLab?

There are options in project settings, but in the "transfer" field, it does not recognize any username or anything. Is it possible to change the owner-permissions and root-privileges?

Comment: what version of gitlab are you using?

Comment: i am using the cloud service at gitlab.com

Comment: have you checked if the target is in your namespace? since you can transfer projects only to namespaces you can manage...

Comment: yes its the account that created the project and its under that accounts name as namespace.

Comment: Some might need to change the origin,  `git remote set-url origin new_url`

Comment: can you see yourself in collaborators??

Answer (score 62):

## TL;DR

Move your project to a new group where both you and the other user are owners, then the other user must transfer it to his own namespace.

## Background

The other answers obviously do not work to transfer a project to a different user, although the comments section of one is enough for someone to figure it out. Also there is [this issue on GitLab itself](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/524) that provides some insights.

#### My Situation

I installed and now administer a few instances of GitLab for a few small developer teams as well as one for my personal projects. Resultingly, I have run into numerous questions about this. I keep coming back to this question only to realize that it was never actually answered correctly.

#### The Namespace Problem

The issue that you face when doing this is that there can only be one owner of a project, but to transfer a project you have to own the namespace that you are transferring it to. To my knowledge there is no other way to move a project. For completeness, I'll add that the namespace here is, e.g., *"gitlab.com/**my-user-name**/..."* or *"gitlab.com/**my-group-name**/..."*.

---

## Solution

Because one user cannot "own" another namespace (not even admins), the only option to set up a scenario where two users own the same namespace is with a group. Perform the following steps to accomplish this.

1. Create a new group.
2. Add the user that you want to transfer your project to as an owner member of that group.
3. Transfer your project to that group (a namespace you manage because you are an owner).
4. Login as the other user, then transfer the group project to the "other user" namespace.

At this point you will be left as a *master* in the project. You can now remove yourself from the project entirely if desired.

Comment: Added the bunny to get people's attention with the bad answers already getting upvoted...

Comment: The link to the gitlab issue is dead. Can you find it again, I would be interested.

Comment: @Lucas I can't find it, because it looks like GitLab changed where the support forum is (if you remove the issue number it is still a 404). Might be migrated here (https://forum.gitlab.com), but I'd check with GitLab on where all of those support tickets moved if you really care about it. It was never stored on web.archive.org AFAICT

Comment: That lead me to find it/something similar autoritative myself: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/14502

Comment: @Toolkit On what version of GitLab? There might be an easier way to do it now...otherwise, "why GitLab, why?"

Comment: @JakeD, gitlab.com,  managed to do it. deleted my comment

Answer (score 1):

You can basically create a group then add the project to a group, then from the group member setting add a new owner and you can leave the group yourself.

See screenshots

[image]

Comment: True, but usually we also want to downgrade our role to simple 'member', which is unfortunately not an option for some reason :S

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to export the project and import it under a different user. This preserves commits and branches.

**Settings** -> **Advanced** -> **Export Project**

Then to import:

**New Project** -> **Import Project** -> **Gitlab Export**

Comment: Is this any different than transferring ownership? This seems like a better way but I am not sure if it has downsides.

Comment: @SinanYaman as they said "preserves commits and branches", especially not issues, merge requests etc.

Comment: in that case clone is easier

Comment: I have done it, seems like perfect for now: commits, branches, issues are all here. The previous members are not added (naturally I think). I am going to it with two other projects too.

Comment: this is not a project transfer of ownership

Comment: Good solution, but "Transfer project" will the best in new versions of `Gitlab`

Answer (score 0):

You can add another owner to the project via:

**Project -> Members -> Add members -> Select Owner as permission**

Next you have to remove yourself from the project:

**Project -> Members -> Click the red button behind your username**

Now you left the project, and the user you entered before is now the owner.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I am not able to fine the "Owner" as  an permission in gitlab's new version ... :( any another tricks.

Comment: You can add yourself as the group owner.

Comment: SO @jvanbaaesen, that means the project must be under any group? It can't be solely transferred to another one, right?

Comment: Doesn't work for me, owner cannot be selected from dropdown on 10.5.5.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this for many projects, it's pretty convenient to do it via API:

```py
import gitlab
gl = gitlab.Gitlab('https://gitlab.com', private_token='...')

gitlab_project = gl.projects.get("the-project-of-yours")
target_group = gl.groups.get("target-group-where-to-land")
gitlab_project.transfer_project(target_group.id)
```

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#transfer-a-project-to-a-new-namespace

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/groups.html#transfer-project-to-group

https://github.com/python-gitlab/python-gitlab/blob/master/gitlab/v4/objects/projects.py#L461

Answer (score -1):

In current version (**10.2.4**) you should do following:

Go to "Project" -> "Settings" -> Expand "Advanced settings" -> Scroll down to "Transfer project"

Comment: Confirm: In v10.8.2 (from 2018) it still works that way. - To find the Gitlab version number, go to the top right corner, click on avatar logo. Pullldown menu opens, choose "Help"

Comment: Nice. It works on `GitLab Community Edition 11.2.3` also. Please export your project before transferring to restore it if needed.

Answer (score -1):

It involves multiple steps, but its possible.

1. Create a group and transfer project to the group
2. Invite new user to the group
3. Login with new user and transfer project to new user from group

#### However I think it is easier to maintain if you leave your repository in the group

Transfer menu are always at
`Project => Settings => Advanced`

Answer (score -3):

In Gitlab 8.8.3 you are able to transfer a project.
Be careful. Changing the project's namespace can have unintended side effects ;)

**Go to Project -> Settings -> Project Settings -> Scroll down to Transfer project**

[image: Change project namespace in Gitlab]

Answer (score -4):

In GitLab Community Edition 9.3.5 if you are administrator you should go to Settings -> Members and change de role of the member you want.

For example, search John Doe, set the developer role, and now John Doe will be developer and won't be owner anymore.