# How to become a normal developer with restricted permissions in a gitlab project that I created?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-7

We are using GitLab 7.7.0.rc4 on our own server. I created a project, which gives me ownership of that project and all permissions, in particular the right to accept merge requests on the master branch. I would like to give up ownership and **become a normal developer (i.e. with restricted permissions)** so that I can not accidentally accept merge requests by pushing to master or pressing the wrong button in the web interface.

How can I achieve this?

I already read https://stackoverflow.com/a/23803494/1460043, but in our gitlab I can not give "Owner" as a role, only Guest/Reporter/Developer/Master.

I already transferred the project to a group namespace, which obviously made the group owner become an owner of the project as well. If I remove myself from the project member list, I loose access to the project. But if I rejoin the project (using the group owner account to add me), I get all permissions back, even if rejoin in the role of a "Guest" only.