# GitLab: admin but can't update my role in a project

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm an admin of a private GitLab project, we have several projects, I can update anyone role inside these projects except me, I only can "Leave"! can you provide any tips in this,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a bit tricky in Gitlab. You can't change the own group. So you could try to login with another user and change it with that user. I haven't tested this yet. Here you can find some good ways to change it.

[How to change the project owner in gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579693/how-to-change-the-project-owner-in-gitlab)

> You can basically create a group then add the project to a group, then from the group member setting add a new owner and you can leave the group yourself.

Some things in Gitlab are a bit strange but perhaps you can solve the problem with one of that solutions.