# How to invite user as owner of GitLab repository?

Tags: gitlab

When I invite a user to a repository member, seems the permission of this user in this repository can only be guest, reporter, developer and maintainer from "Project"->"Setting"->"Member". I can't invite them as owner. How I can invite a user as owner of repository in GitLab?

Comment: Do you want to transfer the ownership? Or share the ownership?

Comment: Perhaps: https://help.github.com/en/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository

Comment: @Loki, share the ownership.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the project owner in gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579693/how-to-change-the-project-owner-in-gitlab)

Comment: @william3031 Git*Lab*

Comment: Yes, it's very close to being a duplicate of the SO @jonrsharpe mentioned. However, the only thing to add is that there can only be one project owner, so you either transfer the ownership, or give the user maintainer privileges.