# How do i delete/remove/leave a GitLab project as OWNER without removing it

Tags: git, gitlab, repository, project

I have a gitlab project i want to leave, but there are more people involved in this project and i dont want to **delete** it. As the **owner** of this project, i have trouble finding the **leave** option. I only find the option to Delete it. Am i missing out on something?

Comment: You need to transfer the ownership to someone else. Does this answer your question? [How to change the project owner in GitLab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579693/how-to-change-the-project-owner-in-gitlab)

Comment: this seems to solve my problem. Thank you very much. But i have one more question. Does it require ANY action from the other members ?