# GitLab: How can I leave a project that I own?

Tags: gitlab

I want to quit a project but I can't find the button for leaving?

I want to leave the *2022_assignment1*: how can I do it?

[image]

Comment: You'll have to transfer ownership to someone else. This post should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579693/how-to-change-the-project-owner-in-gitlab, or maybe delete the project in the project's Settings / General / Advanced

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can leave a project if you're the only owner. But the leave button is in the members list at the far-right of the table (either in `Project information`, or in `Group information`).

If it won't let you leave, you can either archive the project or delete it, in the project's `Settings -> General -> Advanced` section.